# Copy data from one cell to a cell in another sheet based on the value of a second cell in the first sheet?

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy the value of a cell in one sheet to a cell in another sheet based on the value of a third cell ('yes' or blank).
Example:

```
Cell A1: Monday
Cell B1: Yes
```

Copy the value of Cell `A1` into sheet2 Cell `B5` if `B1 = Yes`. If cell `B2` is empty (or 'No') do nothing. Is this possible?
I was trying to do it by using if statement but not having any luck.

[EDIT] Here is my code (but it doesn't work yet):

```
Sub ColorWhite()
Range("B01:B15").Value = Yes

With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = x1ThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End

Range("B01:B15").Value Not Yes
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this formula on Sheet2, cell B5

```
IF(Sheet1!B1 = "Yes", A1, "")
```

If you want to check **both** `B1 = Yes` **and** `nothing` **or** `No` in `B2`:

```
IF(AND(Sheet1!B1 = "Yes", OR(Sheet1!B2 = "", Sheet1!B2="No")), A1, "")
```

And drag and drop it on the range where it is needed

---

[EDIT] Here is a VBA try based on your comment. I kept it simple (there would be more efficient way to do this) so that it is easy to understand and adapt:

```
Sub ColorWhite()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B15")
    If c.Value = "Yes" Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(c.Address).Offset(0, -1)
            .Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(c.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value
            With .Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have come up with another idea to finish the task that I want but unfortunatly I am having difficulty in implementing it.
Sub ColorWhite()

     Range("B01:B15").Value = Yes
        With Selection.Font
            .ThemeColor = x1ThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    
    Range("B01:B15").Value Not Yes
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Likes the first part of the code but not the second part.

Comment: Thanks @JMax for the code, much appreciated. I have edited it slightly to the following:    'Sub ColorWhite()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C121:C150")
    If c.Value = "Yes" Then
        With Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 0)
            .Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value
            With .Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next c
End Sub'

Comment: Thanks for the help, the code did as it was designed to do. However, it changed the formula in the cell to a set text. It was a lot simplier to have used conditional Formatting on the Home Ribbon Menu to do what the code did, but the conditional formatting keeps the cells formula intact. Next I have to find a way to hide the rows that do not have the value as "Yes". I have tried an if statement but this does not work.